# Am I correct in understanding that everything in the Universe is entangled with everything, only to varying degrees?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, quantum-entanglement

Since all quantum fields directly or indirectly constantly interact with each other, can we say that everything in the universe is entangled with everything, only to varying degrees?

Comment: Since the universe includes extreme objects like black holes, would a satisfying answer to this question require considering quantum gravity? If so, you might be interested in [arXiv:1609.00026](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.00026), which outlines the role of entanglement in quantum gravity as we currently understand it (which might not be very well).

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly Thank you for the article. But I didn't understand something. If the degrees of freedom on the two-dimensional boundary are not entangled, then the volumetric space-time disappears?

Comment: Yes, that is the claim. Even in ordinary relativistic QFT, all finite-energy states (including the vacuum) are entangled with respect to location. This is formalized by the Reeh-Schlieder theorem. Most $(D-1)$-dimensional QFTs are **not** equivalent to any $D$-dimensional quantum gravity theory with a conventional spacetime. For such a correspondence to work, the $(D-1)$-dimensional QFT must have some special properties, and then the $D$-dimensional geometry is encoded in the pattern of entanglement in the lower-dimensional QFT's states (according to our current very incomplete understanding).

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly Small clarification. If the degrees of freedom at the boundary are not entangled, then there is no four-dimensional space-time, right? But a quantum field defined on a two-dimensional boundary still exists, right? And if the excitations of this field become entangled, a third dimensional dimension and gravity appear?

Comment: I'm straying outside the boundaries of my own expertise here, so don't take this comment too seriously. My rudimentary understanding is that having the right (not arbitrary) pattern of entanglement is a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for a conventional interior spacetime to exist. *If the degrees of freedom at the boundary are not entangled, then there is no four-dimensional space-time, right?* Right -- but if there's no entanglement at all, then I'm not sure a boundary QFT exists, either. The type of QFT used in this context might not have any states with no entanglement.